# Uncaught TypeError Illegal invocation in node.js using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

**My client side:**

```
var value = socket.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    jQuery.ajax({

        type : 'POST',
        url : 'http://127.0.0.1:5000',
        data : value,
        dataType : 'json',
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
        },
        success : function(str) {
            alert(str);
        },
```

**server side:**

```
var server2 = http.createServer(function(req, res) {

res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type':'application/json'
        });
res.end(JSON.stringify(data()));
```

Comment: I know some browsers have issues with Commas on the last element in the object. After 'application/json' you should remove the comma. Your also missing the ending Ajax }).

Comment: Even removing Commas and adding the ending Ajax }), I am getting the same issue.

Comment: What returns `data()` function?

Comment: It must return the 'value' present in client side in json